# how to get distinct records from Mongodb using PYMONGO

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My collection has 4 documents:

[image]

Both HCL and TCS are repeated twice with different values

I need to find all stocks with only latest values without repetition of stock

In the above example I need result:

```
[
    {
        "stock" : "HCL",
        "price" : 11
    },
    {
        "stock" : "TCS",
        "price" : 21
    }
]
```

It should ignore the previous values and only find the last one for each stock

Can it be done in Mongodb find query? I am using Python through pymongo

Comment: Please include code to show what you have tried. Have you searched for this? MongoDB has great documentation. P.S. Whatever you can not do with "find" you can try to do with the aggregation framework (including this).

Comment: I have tried tihs : 
db.test.distinct('stock') 

it results in :
[ 'HCL', 'TCS' ]

But I need last documents

Comment: add what you have tried to the question, not as a comment. Also, show us what  questions in StackOverflow you have looked at and why they don't answer your question (put this in the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by :

```
r  = coll_LTP.aggregate([
    {"$group": {
        "_id": "$stock",
        "price" :{"$last" : "$price"},
    }},
    # {"$sort": {
    #     "date": -1,
    # }}
  ])
```

Thanks